# About BIOS spec

Tags: assembly, x86

When system power on, BIOS will check storage device's 1st sector, if last two bytes is 0x55aa, then load the sector to 0000H:7C00H. At last jumps to the address.

My problem is that just when cpu switchs to logic address 0000H:7C00H, what are the value of the general purpose registers. I mean that BIOS will transfer some info for the boot sector code, then how BIOS stores the info?

Answer (score 2):

BIOS won't "transfer" info for or to the boot sector. The boot sector is simply read from device, placed into memory, and control passed to it. General purpose registers are not assumed to contain any specific values, and boot loader doesn't need to do any attempt to save and restore their original values before using those general purpose registers. For sake of your question, consider them "undefined".
You may want to distinguish between Master Boot Record (MBR) and Voiume Boot Record (VBR), latter being 2nd level, chainloaded, boot records. But even if you may want to, BIOS is pretty oblivious to the differences.

Comment: The value of the general purpose registers is unknown at that point.  It is similar to c/c++ uninitialized data where it is going to be some random value left in there from another operation used during boot.

Comment: However, the `dl` register contains the boot drive so you can pass it back to BIOS functions.

Comment: @Jester: You cannot even rely on the fact that DL contains the boot drive - especially when using chain loaders. GRUB for example has a configurable option if DL is assumed to contain the boot drive or not.

Comment: You should also be aware that the stack pointer (SS ans SP registers) should be set up correctly by the boot sector because the BIOS' stack may be too small.